# How can HAPI early connection closure warnings be fixed?

Tags: java, hl7, hapi

I'm using [HAPI](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/) to write a simple client and server for HL7v2 messaging. Both client and server appear to work, but are issuing `INFO` level warnings about early socket terminations when sending an acknowledegement message.

The server produces the following:

```
2012-09-17 13:36:38,715 INFO  pool-1-thread-1 [MinLLPReader] End of input stream reached.
2012-09-17 13:36:38,718 INFO  pool-1-thread-1 [Receiver] Closing connection (no more messages available).
```

And the complementary error on the client:

```
2012-09-17 13:36:38,715 INFO  pool-1-thread-1 [MinLLPReader] SocketException on read() attempt.  Socket appears to have been closed: socket closed 
2012-09-17 13:36:38,716 INFO  pool-1-thread-1 [Receiver] Closing connection (no more messages available).
```

**How can I stop these messages from appearing?**

The server code to send an acknowledgement looks like this. Note that I've had to disable all possible message validation components thanks to an "interesting" interpretation of the HL7v2 specification:

```
// HAPI server component
final LowerLayerProtocol llp = LowerLayerProtocol.makeLLP();
final PipeParser parser = new PipeParser();
final SimpleServer server = new SimpleServer(12345, llp, parser, false);

// registers an admission message handler
server.registerApplication("ADT", "A01", new Application() {

    @Override
    public Message processMessage(final Message message) throws ApplicationException, HL7Exception {

        final PipeParser pipeParser = new PipeParser();
        pipeParser.setValidationContext(new NoValidation());
        final String encoded = pipeParser.encode(message);

        final AbstractMessage adtMessage = new ADT_A01();
        adtMessage.setValidationContext(new NoValidation());
        adtMessage.parse(encoded);

        return (ACK) DefaultApplication.makeACK(adtMessage);    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canProcess(final Message message) {
        return true;
    }
});

// tell HAPI not to try to validate incoming messages
server.registerConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {    

    @Override
    public void connectionReceived(final Connection c) {
        c.getParser().setValidationContext(new NoValidation());
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionDiscarded(Connection c) {
        // nothing
    }
}); 

server.start();
```

and the client:

```
ConnectionHub hub = null;
Connection conn = null;

try {

    final ADT_A01 adtMessage = new ADT_A01();
    adtMessage.parse(message); // message content as a string

    hub = ConnectionHub.getInstance();
    final PipeParser connParser = new PipeParser();
    connParser.setValidationContext(new NoValidation());

    conn = hub.attach(host, port, connParser, MinLowerLayerProtocol.class);
    final Initiator init = conn.getInitiator();

    final Message response = init.sendAndReceive(adtMessage);
    final String responseString = connParser.encode(response);
    System.out.println("Received response:\n" + responseString);

}
finally {

    if (conn != null) {
        hub.discard(conn);
    }

    ConnectionHub.shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which logger implementation you use...
For the two classes you mentioned (ca.uhn.hl7v2.app.Receiver, ca.uhn.hl7v2.llp.MinLLPReader), simply set the log level to WARN, and the messages will disappear.

Christian

Comment: Setting log level to `warn` works fine but I am concerned whether the messages are relevant or not.